# How can I select features by map clicks

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, select, feature-layer

I'm developing a flex web application using the ArcGIS flex API 3.1. 
I have a map with a polyline feature layer. I'd like to be able to select polylines from the map by clicking on the features on the map.

Could you guide me to a sample?

Regards.

Comment: [Select Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Selecting_features_interactively/00s50000000w000000/) in the Tools toolbar sounds like the simple solution, unless I am not fully understanding your question.

Comment: I forgot to precise that I'm developing a flex web application. I'm not on ArcMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. An answer can be found here:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/75997-Getting-feature-layer-graphic-on-map-click